What is the minimal genus of a surface acted on by the symmetric group $S_n$?
For $G$ a finite group, it is easy to construct a (connected, orientable) surface with a faithful action of $G$. E.g.: take a disjoint union of $G$ many spheres, and add a 1-handle for every edge in the Cayley graph of $G$.

What is known about the minimal genus of a surface faithfully acted upon by the symmetric group $S_n$?

(Same question may be asked for other families of finite groups.)

For example, I believe that $S_3$ acts faithfully on $T^2$. Think of $T^2$ as a regular hexagon where opposing edges are identified in an orientation preserving way. Then picking every second vertex gives a regular triangle. The canonical $S_3$ action can (also rather canonicallly) be extended to the entire $T^2$. Of course we have a global fixed point in the middle, but faithful only means that no group element acts as the identity.

But on the other hand $S_4$ already acts faithfully on $S^2$, by extending the canonical action on an tetrahedron, i.e. we get for an larger $n$ an even smaller genus.

The case of $g=0$ and $g=1$ you can do by hand (and don't include $S_n$ for $n \ge 5$), but for higher genus you can't do better asymptotically than $O(|G|) = O(n!)$ (with an obvious explicit constant) by the Hurwitz bound. (compare https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179785/finite-subgroups-of-mapping-class-groups). So the only question is whether you care about the constant.

I just realized -- do you mean a holomorphic action, or do you also allow anti-holomorphic maps? Because I think that Condor's paper, which I cited below, should show that $S_n$ acts on a surface with $n! = 168 (g-1)$, if you allow anti-holomorphic maps.

@DavidESpeyer My intention was to allow anti-holomorphic maps, but I realise that I might have been ambiguous.

@DavidESpeyer Your last comment is a complete answer to my question.

About existence: $\pi_1(\Sigma_2)$ ($\Sigma_g$ closed surface of genus $g$) has a $S_n$ quotient, which yields a Galois covering of genus $1+n!$ with free action of $S_n$.

I don't have a precise answer, but the genus of $S$ has to grow like $n!$.
To see this, note that when $n$ is large enough, $S$ cannot be the sphere or torus.  So $S$ admits hyperbolic metrics.  By Nielsen realisation (due to Kerckhoff) the surface $S$ admits a hyperbolic metric invariant under the $S_n$ action.  The quotient is an orbifold.  So it has area greater than or equal to the area of the $(2, 3, 7)$-triangle in the hyperbolic plane.  That is, it has area at least $\pi/42$.  So $S$ has area at least $n! \cdot \pi/42$.  Since the area of $S$ equals $2\pi(2g - 2)$ we deduce that the genus is bounded below by a linear function of $n!$.

Added by André Henriques:
David Speyer and Nick Gill have shown, in the comments, that for $n$ large enough (specifically $\ge 167$), the symmetric group $_$
acts faithfully on a surface of genus $g$, with $−1=\frac{!}{168}$. As argued above, this is optimal.

The question of whether the optimal bound can be attained is equivalent to the question of whether the finite group $G$ can be written as a quotient of the $(2,3,7)$ Coxeter group. I.e., whether it's a (2,3,7)-group. So my question is: is the symmetric group a (2,3,7)-group? Apparently, G. Higman has an unpublished paper in which he showed that every sufficiently large alternating group is a
(2, 3, 7)-group...

We can't get equality in the Hurwitz bound. Equality happens for a group $G$ iff $G$ is generated by elements $x$, $y$, $z$ obeying $x^2=y^3=z^7=xyz=1$. But $y^3=z^7=1$ forces $y$ and $z$ in $A_n$, and then $x = z^{-1} y^{-1}$ forces $x$ in $A_n$.

@AndréHenriques Higman's paper is unpublished, but Condor has a published paper where he makes Higman's bound explicit: Condor, "Generators for alternating and symmetric groups" (1980) shows that $A_n$ is a Hurwitz group for $n \geq 168$.

Minor correction:  The $(2,3,7)$ Coxeter group and the $(2,3,7)$ triangle group aren't the same thing. The former is $\langle p,q,r \rangle / \langle p^2=q^2 = r^2 = (pq)^2=(qr)^3=(rp)^7=1 \rangle$, the latter is the index $2$ subgroup generated by $x=pq$, $y=qr$, $z=rp$, with relations as in my previous comment. I think (but am not sure) that the $(2,3,7)$ Coxeter group is the one which Condor gives a different presentation for on page 1 of his paper.

@DavidESpeyer Thanks David for the correction. So, while $S_n$ is not a $(2,3,7)$-group [i.e. it's not a quotient of the $(2,3,7)$-triangle group], it might still be a quotient of the $(2,3,7)$-Coxeter group.

@DavidESpeyer, I think you mean Conder rather than Condor.

On p.745 of Regular maps with an alternating or symmetric
group as automorphism group, Conder writes "It was shown by the author in his 1980 doctoral thesis [3] that both the alternating group $A_n$ and the symmetric group $S_n$ are smooth quotients of the extended $(2, 3, 7)$ triangle group for all $n\geq 167$". Note that the extended $(2,3,7)$ triangle group is the same as the $(2,3,7)$ Coxeter group. @AndréHenriques, does that deal with your query above?

Note that, subsequent to the quote in my comment above, Conder asserts that "a reasonably detailed summary was given in [4]" where [4] is the 1980 reference that @DavidESpeyer has already mentioned.

@NickGill. Thank you to both Nick and David. Your comments completely answer my question.
